# Need some specification on how to resolve below code?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(true_k):
 print(“Cluster %d”, % i),
 for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
 print(‘ %s’ % terms[ind])
```

Error says as below

```
for i in range(true_k):
 print(“Cluster %d”, % i),
 for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
 print(‘ %s’ % terms[ind])
  File "<ipython-input-21-459006fea4dd>", line 2
    print(“Cluster %d”, % i),
                 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: You can't use "smart" quotes, i.e. `“”‘’`, to delimit string literals. Use a quote or apostrophe character, i.e. `"` or `'`.

Comment: It looks like you aren't using a text editor to type your code.  Your quotes have been translated to "smart quotes".  What program are you using to write your code?

Answer (score 0):

`print(“Cluster %d”, % i)`

should be

`print(“Cluster %d” % i)`

You don't need the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved.Thanks everyone for your response i am pretty new in coding. 
The comma was definitely a mistake and then i wrote my code as below

```
for i in range(true_k):
 print('Cluster'+ '%s' % i),
 for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
  print(' %s' % terms[ind])
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I have reason to believe you're writing your code in word or something due to having smart quotes and poor indentation. Go download [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) and lookup how to use it, it's a very popular IDE and will assist you greatly in programming. As well as typing the correct type of quotation marks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you need.

```
for i in range(true_k):
      print("Cluster {}".format(i))
      for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
         print("{}".format(terms[ind]))
```

Comment: No, they need to fix their quotes; not have a different method of formatting.